# Anylogic: Bug in "Choose Probability Distribution..." wizard after update to PLE 8.8.0

Tags: probability, anylogic, wizard

After updating Anylogic to PLE 8.8.0 (macOS 10.13.6), "Choose Probability Distribution..." wizard is not showing any description of distributions and labels of arguments are just labeled as "arg0", "arg1", "arg2"...

Is anyone else experiencing the same?

[image: wizard screenshot]

Tnx!

Comment: Can you flag this with support@anylogic.com so they become aware, pls?

Answer (score 1):

correct.. this seems to be a bug, not only with distributions but many functions now have arg instead of the name of the variable that is indicative of its meaning